# PivotTable with Apache POI and reference from other sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

I've been trying to create Pivot table via Apache POI

The data I use is in another sheet whereas I'm trying to create new sheet for Pivot table

I tried the following

`XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("license_pivot_table");
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(new AreaReference("license_usage!D:E"), new CellReference("A1"));`

My data is in Sheet named "license_usage" and in columns D & E and wanted to put the pivot table in A1 of the license_pivot_table sheet

This ends up in null pointer exception

How can I refer the data from another sheet in Apache POI?

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass a reference to the sheet that holds the Data range as a third parameter to the createPivotTable call.

something like

```
XSSFSheet license_usage = wb.getSheet("license_usage");
XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("license_pivot_table");
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(new AreaReference("license_usage!D:E"), new CellReference("A1"),license_usage);
```

This is demonstrated in this excellent article. (all credit to the author - I am just passing along what I learned there)

http://thinktibits.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/Create-Pivot-Table-Java-Apache-POI-Example.html